# Wrong number of parameters of TRIM function in Hibernate @Formula

Tags: hibernate, parameters, formula, trim

I'm trying to make a formula to select a user-friendly name of the user profile. It selects **firstname + ' ' + lastname** if at least one of them is not null and not blank (contains non-whitespace characters), otherwise it selects **shortname** (with the same conditions) and, finally, if **shortname** is blank or null, it selects **id**, converted to string.

```
@Formula("COALESCE(NULLIF(TRIM(BOTH FROM CONCAT(sp.firstname, ' ', sp.lastname)), ''), TRIM(p.shortname), to_char(p.id, 'FM9999999999999999')) " +
   "FROM socialprofile AS sp " +
   "JOIN profile AS p ON sp.id=p.id")
   public String getUserFriendlyName() {
      return super.getUserFriendlyName();
   }
```

The result is:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unexpected number of trim function operands : 10
```

but there is only 3 arguments: BOTH, FROM and result of CONCAT. Is there any workaround of this issue? DB is PostgreSQL 9.1, Hibernate version is 4.2.1.
Just in case, here's the table structure:

```
Profile
  bigint id
  text shortname

SocialProfile
  bigint id
  text firstname
  text lastname
```

They are related as One-to-One by **id** field, in Java code SocialProfile extends Profile. In PgAdmin SQL editor this request works perfectly.

Answer (score 5):

I faced this problem too. It appears that `@Formula` delegates to [Hibernate's internal "where template" parser](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/5.0.0.Final/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/sql/Template.java#L209) which doesn't expect another function nested in `trim()`. This issue was reported as [HHH-5970](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-5970) before, but they didn't do any thing with it.

The work around was straight forward: don't use `trim()` this way in a `@Formula`. Instead use e.g. `ltrim(rtrim(..))` or even a DB-specific regex function which replaces `"^\s+|\s+$"` by `""`, depending on the capabilities of the DB being used.

PostgreSQL supports `ltrim()` and `rtrim()`, so this should do for you:

```
@Formula("COALESCE(NULLIF(LTRIM(RTRIM(BOTH FROM CONCAT(sp.firstname, ' ', sp.lastname))), '') [...]"
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced many issues with Formula annotation as well due to Hibernate changing the content of the formula in order to be able to append to the original query.
This led me to use db views in these cases instead of using unpredictable Hibernate Formula.